# ERROR this.subnodeSelectAllItemtext.push is not a function in angular2+

Tags: angular, neo4j

I am trying to integrate Angular2+ with Neo4j application. 
I have created a search and used ng-multiselect-dropdown - its module is -

```
import { NgMultiSelectDropDownModule } from 'ng-multiselect-dropdown';
```

**Error**

```
 ERROR TypeError: this.subnodeSelectAllItemtext.push is not a function
at HierarchySearchComponent.onSelectAllSubNode (hierarchy- 
search.component.ts:155)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (HierarchySearchComponent.html:27)
at handleEvent (core.js:11107)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:12204)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:11907)
at dispatchEvent (core.js:8561)
at eval (core.js:10044)
at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:3724)
at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:253)
at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:191)
```

I use a function -

**app.component.ts**

```
onSelectAllSubNode(items: any) {
this.subnodeSelect = true;

console.log("On Item select all" + items);

var subnodeLength = items.length;
console.log("subnodeLength = ", subnodeLength);
this.subnodeSelectAllItem = items;
console.log("subnodeSelectAllItem = ", this.subnodeSelectAllItem);

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

  this.subnodeSelectAllItemtext.push(items[i].item_text);
  console.log("subnodeSelectAllItem-text = ", 
   this.subnodeSelectAllItemtext);

  if(i== items.length){
    return;
  }
```

}

**app.component.html**

```
<!-- ng-multiselect-dropdown for SubNodes-->
<div>
  <p  id = "subnode" >Select a SubNode or Multiple Nodes - </p>
  <p style="width:50%">
    <ng-multiselect-dropdown [placeholder]="'Select SubNodes'" [data]="dropdownList" [(ngModel)]="selectedItems" [settings]="dropdownSettings"
      (onSelect)="onItemSelectSubNode($event)" (onSelectAll)="onSelectAllSubNode($event)">
    </ng-multiselect-dropdown>
     </p>
    </div>
```

**Image -**

[image: Image of Search Subnode]

I get error on Select All i.e. selecting All the attributes. Please help me resolve my error.

Comment: please show how you declared  `this.subnodeSelectAllItemtext`

Comment: Hi Artyon.... check this  declaration--> subnodeSelectAllItemtext = [];